# Is There A Better Way to Add Entropy to Array of Ints?

Tags: c#, arrays, entropy

I needed to take an array of (C#) integers and randomly reassign values to make the values "feel" more randomized, without changing the length or sum of the array.  But this array can get quite large, so I'm wondering if anyone has a better way to do this.  Basically, the array initially contains values that are roughly the sum divided by the length, with one element having the remainder.  What I am using now is:

```
    static int[] AddEntropy(int[] ia)
    {

        int elements = ia.Length;
        int sum = ia.Sum();

        for (int runs = 0; runs < (elements * 2); runs++)
        {

            Random rnd = new Random(int.Parse(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
            int rndi = rnd.Next(0, (sum / elements));
            int rnde1 = rnd.Next(0, elements);
            int rnde2 = rnd.Next(0, elements);
            if (rndi < 1 ) rndi = 1;

            if (ia[rnde1] > (rndi + 2))
            {
                ia[rnde1] = ia[rnde1] - rndi;
                ia[rnde2] = ia[rnde2] + rndi;
            }

        }

        return ia;
    }
```

Any thoughts on making this perform better would be appreciated.  It seems to perform "well", but if the array are larger than my sample of five elements (up to 1000 elements), and there are several arrays that may be modified in quick succession, a speedier option would be great.

Comment: As an additional note, no element should ever be 0.  Also, I'm using elements as the limiter in the for loop since it doesn't need to run 100 times for a five element array, but 10 times for a 1000 element array wouldn't likely randomize too much.

Comment: If you have working code and are looking for improvements, [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better fit than StackOverflow.

Comment: That looks like a bit of a strange way of creating a new `Random`. But I agree with @dcastro - probably best ask on Code Review.

Comment: Moving the `rnd` to an outer scope, and using the default seed instead of creating your own *expensive* seed inside a tight loop would help immensely, for one.

Comment: the RNGCryptoServiceProvider coud be a viabe solution?

Comment: `ia.OrderBy(i => rnd.Next()).ToArray()` is a hundred times simpler and may be fast enough for most purposes, give it a try.

Comment: Shuffle and OrderBy don't change the value of the elements.  They don't need to be in any particular order, and the values stored in each element need to be changed by random increments.

I apologize, I'll check out CodeReview - thank you.

Good call on creating rnd outside of the loop - not sure what I was thinking there.  And I suppose the default seed should be fine - I just generally avoid the default seed, purely out of habit more than out of necessity.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: @JesseWilliams the default seed is perfectly fine unless a) instances of `Random` are being created in quick succession (which won't happen if `rnd` is moved to an outer scope) or b) there are security implications, in which case you might need [dedicated hardware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator). Best of luck

Comment: If you care about speed mostly - consider pre-creating array of white noise with characteristics you like (i.e. sum = 0) and simply adding it to your source array (maybe with repletion).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I thought about something similar, and while it would be speedy, I don't know that it would suit my purpose.

The input array is different every time, and generated when the user clicks a form button.  They choose x devices and y items (total).  The array then is generated with x elements, and each element is y/x, except for the last which is the remainder.  However, prior to being used (for output), I need those values randomized, but always maintaining a sum of y and always keeping x elements.

Comment: I tried creating the array initially by looping through the elements and assigning them a random value of 1,y, then decremented y.  In the end, though, the last few elements almost always ended up being 1 as y decreased.

Comment: To extend on what @dcastro was saying, I would move `rnd` even further out and pass it in as a parameter to `AddEntropy`. You say *"there are several arrays that may be modified in quick succession"* so you still may run the risk of two calls to `AddEntropy` getting the same seed, by creating the `Random` in whatever code that will be frequently calling `AddEntropy` you don't need to worry about it happening.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Wouldn't those both result in the same seed being used if they were called that quickly in succession?

Comment: You are using the same `Random` instance for both calls (instead of making a new Random inside the call) so you will not need to worry about "the same seed". the two calls will produce different results no matter how fast you call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood everything correctly the task requires the sum of the elements to be preserved. Then there is no need in initial array elements values, the two thing that matter are the sum of the elements and the number of the elements.

```
public static int[] GetArray(int sum, int n)
{
    if(sum < n)
        throw new ArgumentException("sum is lower than n");
    Random rnd = new Random();

    // reserve 1 for each of the elements
    sum -= n;

    // generate random weights for every element in sum
    int[] w = new int[n];
    int sw = 0;             
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        w[i] = rnd.Next(0, 100);
        sw += w[i];
    }

    // generate element values based on their weights
    int[] result = new int[n];
    int tsum = 0;
    int psum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        tsum += w[i] * sum;
        result[i] = tsum / sw - psum;
        psum += result[i];
    }

    // restore reserved ones
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        result[i]++;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: instead of having `w` be a `int[]` I would just make it a `double[]` and then call `w[i] = rnd.NextDouble()` that gives you the same 0 to 100% weight (although scalled 0 to 1 instead of 0 to 100)

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain You are right. However I didn't want to work with doubles as they give error. One might just increase MAX value in rnd.Next(0, MAX) while keeping an eye on accumulators not to overflow. Int64 type will be better for them.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko Thank you for the above code.  As absolutely simple as it is, I never thought to reserve 1 for each element.  Also, the weights are a good way to solve the issue.  I may have to see what the overall speed different is, but I imagine there should be a reasonable benefit to how your sample operates.